# Changing the order of frames

Tags: frames

I generated multiple frames by `C-x 5 ...`.
Is there a way to change the order of frame when we visit using `C-x 5 o` ?

Comment: Order of frames is sequential, but you can jump between them. If you mean previous frame instead next, use `C-u - C-x 5 o`. If you mean nth frame, 2 in this case, you can use `C-u 2 C-x 5 o`.  Question should be clarified anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to change the order of frames used by `C-x 5 o` (commmand `other-frame`). It uses functions `next-frame` and `previous-frame`, which are coded in C.

You can, however, define your own command, getting the list of frames using `(frame-list)` and then sorting them any way you like or accessing any one you like.